# Loss suddenly becomes Nan when training

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nan

I built a neural network using pytorch for anomaly detection. The network structure is shown below.

```
def __init__(self, hyp):
    super(DAGMM, self).__init__()

    layers = []
    layers += [nn.Linear(hyp['input_dim'], hyp['hidden1_dim'])]
    layers += [nn.Tanh()]
    layers += [nn.Linear(hyp['hidden1_dim'], hyp['hidden2_dim'])]
    layers += [nn.Tanh()]
    layers += [nn.Linear(hyp['hidden2_dim'], hyp['hidden3_dim'])]
    layers += [nn.Tanh()]
    layers += [nn.Linear(hyp['hidden3_dim'], hyp['zc_dim'])]

    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    layers = []
    layers += [nn.Linear(hyp['zc_dim'], hyp['hidden3_dim'])]
    layers += [nn.Tanh()]
    layers += [nn.Linear(hyp['hidden3_dim'], hyp['hidden2_dim'])]
    layers += [nn.Tanh()]
    layers += [nn.Linear(hyp['hidden2_dim'], hyp['hidden1_dim'])]
    layers += [nn.Tanh()]
    layers += [nn.Linear(hyp['hidden1_dim'], hyp['input_dim'])]

    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    layers = []
    layers += [nn.Linear(hyp['zc_dim'] + 2, hyp['hidden3_dim'])]
    layers += [nn.Tanh()]
    layers += [nn.Dropout(p=hyp['dropout'])]
    layers += [nn.Linear(hyp['hidden3_dim'], hyp['n_gmm'])]
    layers += [nn.Softmax(dim=1)]

    self.estimation = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    self.lambda1 = hyp['lambda1']
    self.lambda2 = hyp['lambda2']
```

I set 10 epochs. When I used my data for training, the loss`(based on the reconstruction error)` performed well at first and kept decreasing, but when it came to a certain batch of the 3rd epoch, the loss suddenly became `Nan`.

After I tried again, the Nan situation still appeared, but not at the same moment.

```
Time 7549.04, Epoch [3/10], Iter [1400/5318], lr 0.0001 loss 15.2830, recon_error 15.2196, energy -7.7528

Time 7667.87, Epoch [3/10], Iter [1600/5318], lr 0.0001 loss nan, recon_error nan, energy nan
```

There are no Nan samples in my data, and I don't know why this unstable situation occurs.

Comment: Try looking into the specific instances which lead to the diminishing or exploding gradient would suggest using an optimizer like AdamW or a learning rate scheduler. You can also try the PyTorch lightning and apply a different learning rate for each encoder decoder without a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Here I would say that the problem is not directly the model. The most probable thing is that your gradient step computed for a given batch explodes, i.e. is too large and yields to a Nan in the loss. There are countermeasures that you can try :

- Normalize the dataset
- Reduce the learning rate of the optimizer, either the static value, or with a learning rate scheduler
- Insert batch normalization layers after the activation functions (tanh)

Answer (score 0):

Softmax is defined via exponential functions, which can overflow if the input gets large (somewhere around 1e+40). It's unusual for the net to go there, as even if you have entries that can be predicted with p=1, float precision limits any gain at that scale. You can try to verify/solve this using `torch.clamp` right before the Softmax.